# Suppress ComplexInfinity/Indeterminate error

Tags: warning-messages

i am running a loop of calculations, where errors or results like `ComplexInfinity` and `Indeterminate` appear. 
My parameters are encapsulated with `Association` and some of the parameters calculated are reinserted in the next calculation 
E.g.

```
Para =
{Association[{x -> 1, y -> 2, z -> 3, w -> 4}],
   Association[{x -> 5, y -> 0, z -> 0, w -> 6}],
   Association[{x -> 7, y -> 8, z -> 9, w -> 0}]};
j[s_] := (s[z]/s[y]);
u[s_] := (Log[s[w]/s[y]]) + j[s] + 1/(2 \Pi*s[w]);
u /@ Para
```

with the following error/result

`{3/2 + 1/(8 \[Pi]) + Log[2], Indeterminate, Indeterminate}`

my actual model is quite long and i am looking for a solution not to write the model all over again for every row of my encapsulated parameters. I know what this error means. But is there a way to tell Mathematica to suppress specific expressions or terms within an equation so it won´t return an error, but an actual result?

Thank you in advance

Comment: see the basic examples in [Quiet](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html)?

Comment: I want terms within the Equation to return 0. In some ```Association``` rows i will have a result, but in some will occure an error. I want a result even though i have terms in my equation which will have a 0 in the numerator or in the denominator  . Quiet will only suppress the message error, right? And further will suppress my term for all my calculation, even though there won´t be 0?!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want.  `Quiet` only suppresses messages; it does not suppress terms, that is, parts of a calculation, if that's what you mean.  You seems to use the words "error" and "result" in a way that makes me wonder whether you would consider `Indeterminate` an error or a result. To me, it is a result. An error may have caused the result, but it is the result. It seems you might want a different result for `Log[0]+1/0`, what you call an "actual result," but I have no idea what that might be. `Indeterminate` seems the correct result.

Comment: ok Thank your! Because of my model i become the result ```Indeterminate```. my question is how i become an actual result. In case of the second row of parameters ```x -> 5, y -> 0, z -> 0, w -> 6``` the first and second term of my equation (```u[s_] := Log[s[w]/s[y]] + j[s] + 1/(2 \[Pi]*s[w])``` )return an error because my denominator equals 0, but the third term has the result 0.0265 which i want mathematica to return me as the final result, and ignore the first and second term. How can i tell Mathematica to do so?

Comment: Very strange interpretation of evaluation results, but if you insist this can be done like this: `Head[u[s]] @@@ (Quiet[head @@@ (u[s] /. Para) /. s[x_] :> x] /. DirectedInfinity[___] :> Sequence[])`.